# Name of the board for DS18B20s

Tags: breadboard, ds18b20

I was referred in another post with a picture of a board that looks like attached picture. What is the name of the board. Also if I require step up resistors would there be a place I could add that to this board.

. [image]

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't really Pi related. You may be better off asking in https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: "Any advice would be appreciated." you should beware of any non-Pi related "advice"; many of the Answers on this site need to be taken with a grain of salt. You would be better to follow the original advice to ask on E&E.

Comment: You can google with key words "rpi" "io" "breakbout" "hat" "board" "3 pin" "jst" "dupoint“ ”2.55mm“ ”2mm“ etc to narrow down what you want.  A popular general purpose rpi proto hat for multiple sensors or relays is the following: https://www.amazon.com/Alchemy-Power-Pi-EzConnect-Raspberry-connector/dp/B01FE9EQ88

Comment: i think that is a custom board that somebody made at home